# Is it possible to configure default access spec (package private) to public?

Tags: java, default, access-specifier

Is there a compiler flag that can make that happen, or is that default "cemented" in the language?

Comment: Note that if there was a way to do this, there would be no way to explicitly ask for default access because, well, there's no syntax for it.  You'd be stuck with just public, protected and private.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I would be ok with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no standard compiler flag to change that aspect of the language. The only way that I know of to circumvent access limitations is via reflection (and `setAccessible` method), and that depends on the SecurityManager allowing access.